# There is a way to use DOMParser().parseFromString() to create just the element HTML without it creates too the tags <html>, <head> and <body>?

Tags: javascript, domparser

I "fetch" some content from html pages to append it to my content, there is no problem with the code, but I was wondering if there is a better way to use the DOMParse.parseFromString() since after I parse the html string it create a unnecessary basic html structure like `<html>, <head> and <body>` with my element inside, so after parse I have to use a **querySelector()** to get my element inside the page html that it creates.
My question is there is any way to just create the element without this tags?
my code is like this:

```js
function insertFormAddAlunoHTML(){
  fetch('./myElementHTML.html')
  .then((res)=> res.text()) // => <div id='myElement'></div>
  .then((stringElement)=>{
   return new DOMParser().parseFromString(stringElement, 'text/html');
      /*  adds a unecessary html structure like:
      <html>
        <head></head>
        <body>
        <div id='myElement'></div>
        </body>
      </html> */
    })
  .then((html)=>{
//get the element inside the page
    let myElement = html.querySelector('#myElement');
  }).catch((err)=> console.log(err));
}
```

Comment: `return new DOMParser().parseFromString(stringElement, 'text/html').body.firstElementChild` ?

Comment: I think this is far better than use a querySelector in the next then, pls post as an answer so I can mark it as the right answer and close the question. tks @Bravo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
return new DOMParser().parseFromString(stringElement, 'text/html').body.firstElementChild;
```

Comment: this returns only the first one

Comment: @inux correct, it answers the question as required. You are allowed to use alternatives like `.body.children` or `.body.childNodes` per your exact requirements.